# DataTable fnRowCallback link undefined for json

Tags: json, datatable, hyperlink, undefined

I'm dealing with creating link in DataTable from json data. Things going to be good but the link name is not appears to be right. It keeps saying 'undefined' whatever I tried to change. Here's my codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#tablez').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sAjaxSource": 'inc/all_cars_json.php',
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],                   
             "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="car/=' + nRow[0] + '">' +
                        nRow[1] + '</a>');
                    return nRow;
                }
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

JSON data:

```
{"aaData": [
["2715","Toyota","Soluna","VIOS 1.5E VVT-i","2007","\u0e14\u0e33","430,000"],
["2589","Toyota","","MIGHTY X","1995","\u0e40\u0e02\u0e35\u0e22\u0e27","159,000"],["2997","Mazda","Fighter","Freestyle CAB TURBO","2003","\u0e1a\u0e23\u0e2d\u0e19\u0e0b\u0e4c\u0e40\u0e07\u0e34\u0e19","329,000"],
["3002","Isuzu","Rodeo","LS 4WD","2000","\u0e1a\u0e23\u0e2d\u0e19\u0e0b\u0e4c\u0e17\u0e2d\u0e07","319,000"],
["3126","Toyota","Hilux","TIGER D4D CAB","2003","\u0e02\u0e32\u0e27","465,000"],["3127","Mitsubishi","Triton","DID Commonrail","2006","\u0e1a\u0e23\u0e2d\u0e19\u0e0b\u0e4c\u0e17\u0e2d\u0e07","455,000"],
["3128","Honda","City","1.5 i-VTEC","2009","\u0e14\u0e33","0"]
]}
```

Here is the preview:

[image]
**The question is** : How can I have a link title and value (nRow[0]) works in this case.
Regards,

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using:

```
     "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
            $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="car/=' + nRow[0] + '">' +
                $('td:eq(1)', nRow)[1].textConent + '</a>');
            return nRow;
        }
```

Or name your columns

```
"aoColumns": [
              { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "34px", "mDataProp": "Id" },
              { "mDataProp": "Brand" },
              { "mDataProp": "Type" },
              { "mDataProp": "SubType" },
              { "mDataProp": "Year" }]
```

Then you can use this:

```
 "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="car/=' + nRow[0] + '">' +
            aData.Brand + '</a>');
        return nRow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `nRow` to `aData` in the `fnRowCallback` function.

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="car/=' + aData[0] + '">' +
                        aData[1] + '</a>');
                }
```